# A prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ that is not maximal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

So, I've just proven that $I = \{(a,0): a \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ (Operations defined coordinate per coordinate). But I can't get a grip on how to begin to prove that $I$ is not maximal.

The only thing I think about is that, if $I$ is maximal, the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / I$ is a field, since $1 = (1,1) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ is it's unity.

I just need a hint on how to approach this problem.

Any help or response is much apreciated.

Comment: What is $(\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z)/I?$ Is it a field? Alternatively, you just need to find a bigger ideal.

Comment: If $I$ is maximal, then the totient ring $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / I$ is a field. This is a theorem. More generally: if $A$ is a ring with unity and $I$ maximal ideal of $A$, then the totient ring $A/I$ is a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Your ideal is properly contained in $\mathbb{Z}\times 2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Or in any principal Ideal $n \cdot \mathbb{Z}$... So, if $I$ is maximal, then $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \simeq \mathbb{Z} \times n \cdot \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: *Equal*, not isomorphic. Maximality of ideals is about the ideals as subsets of the given ring, not as abstract algebraic objects in themselves.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

$\;\;\;\;\;$ From the OP then $I=\Bbb Z\times\{0\}$. By the first homomorphism theorem then  $$\frac{\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z}{\Bbb Z\times\{0\}}\approx\Bbb Z$$ as $\Bbb Z\times\{0\}$ is the kernel of the ring epimorphism  $\pi:\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ defined by $\pi(x,y)=y$.

$\;\;\;\;\;$ $\Bbb Z$ is an integral domain but not a field. Therefore, $\Bbb Z\times\{0\}$ is a prime $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ ideal but not a maximal one.